# Thumbnail to image swap onclick

Tags: jquery, css, image

I'm trying to get my head around a simple image gallery.

I have a large image in the center and two thumbnails, one at the top left and one the bottom right.

```
<div class="images_gallery">
    <div class="small_top_left thumbnail"> <a href="#triggerlarge"></a><img src="small_top_A.jpg"/></div>

        <div class="large middle visible"><img src="large_imageC.jpg"></div>
        <div class="large middle hidden"><img src="large_imageA.jpg"></div>
        <div class="large middle hidden"><img src="large_imageB.jpg"></div>

    <div class="small_bottom_right thumbnail"> <a href="#triggerlarge"></a><img src="small_bottom_B.jpg"/></div>    
</div>
```

I'm guessing you have three large images, one being visible and the other two large images hidden behind it. When you click the thumbnail it brings up its larger version and swaps thumbnails with the previous large image.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offtopic: Always try to use ids on elements you want to reference from jquery, it improves the performance dramatically.

But, what you were asking i'd do it like this...

markup:

```
 <div id="images_gallery">
  <div class="small_top_left thumbnail"><img src="small_A.jpg" data-image='A'/></div>

    <div class="large middle"><img src="large_imageC.jpg" data-image='C'></div>
 <div class="small_bottom_right thumbnail"> <img src="small_B.jpg" data-image='B'/></div>
 </div>
```

js:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     $("#images_gallery .thumbnail img").click(function() {

          var next_data = $("#images_gallery .large img").attr('data-image');
          var next_thumb = "small_" + next_data + ".jpg";

          var large_data = $(this).attr("data-image");
          var large = "large_image"+ large_data +".jpg";

          $("#images_gallery .large img").attr('src', large).attr('data-image', large_data);
          $(this).attr('src', next_thumb).attr('data-image', next_data); 
     });


});
```

Call images small_A.jpg, small_B.jpg, small_C.jpg, 
and large_image_A.jpg...

Comment: Fantastic @max you have really helped me. Thanks!